# Ajax call in Internet Explorer IE 7 & IE8 error

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

My code in javascript file:

```
$("#login").click(function(){


    username=$("#user_name").val();
    password=$("#password").val();
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "login.php",
        data: "username="+username+"&password="+password,
        success: function(value)
        {
           //code


        },
        beforeSend:function()
        {
             $("#add_err").html("Loading...")
        }
    });
     return false;
});
```

The aboue code is working fine in chrome and firefox but it is not workin in internet explorer 7 and 8.

When i try to access that page in in Internet Explorer 7 it showing the following error message:

"object doesn't support this property or method"

Please suggest me a solution how to overcome this problme in IE7

Comment: I assume in your `success` function where you have `//code` you've just mistyped and left out a `if` statement? Otherwise this could be your issue.

Comment: That looks ok barring the missing `if{..`, if you want a diagnosis you cant substitute real code for `//code`

Comment: BTW you shoudl really declare yoru variable using the `var` keyword if you haven't done that already. e.g. `var username=$("#user_name").val();`

Comment: Looks okay. Do you have a line number or which object it's complaining about?

Comment: It showing error on this line:   $.ajax({  Where there is a ajax call

Comment: yes, we tried using jQuery.ajax for $.ajax still it showing the same error message

Comment: I know that there are many people on IE 7 and IE 8, but seriously till you don't stop developing and not force people to upgrade their browsers, they will keep using it, and you will keep having trouble developing your applications and making them compatible with IE7 & IE8.

Comment: @ArjunBajaj - that comment is totally invalid if someone has Windows XP you know.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss you can always switch to a more modern browser like Chrome or Firefox, and those work pretty well on XP, at least better than IE. :P

Comment: @ArjunBajaj - Not always is that possible if clients do not have those due to internal standards/requirements. Just saying, we as developers cannot dictate the browser in all cases but clients CAN dictate which they will use for whatever reasons they have, some of which may be unknown to us.  YOU can choose not to have them as clients of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the following changes in my code:

```
 username=$("#user_name").val();
  password=$("#password").val();
```

instead of those above lines replaced with those following lines:

```
var username=$("#user_name").val();
  var password=$("#password").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
contentType: "application/json",
```

You may also need to add:

```
dataType: "json",
```

OR

```
dataType: "text",
```

hard to tell from you example exactly what is being returned...